# How to Write a Bash Script that Finds a certain File Type and Uploads it to FTP?

Tags: bash, ftp, find, scp

I'm trying to write a bash script that will run in terminal and will find all the files of a certain type and then upload each file it finds to an ftp server.

I'm relatively new to all this, but I feel like I've searched pretty extensively. I'd like to avoid dealing with SSH Keys if possible.

The closest I've gotten is...

```
find . -exec scp {} $USER@$HOST:$remote_dir \;
```

...but that requires entering a password for each file, which I can't figure out how to write a script for.

Any help or insight would be very appreciated.

Comment: you could try using [sshpass](http://sshpass.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: ...but SSH keys are good!

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it with the default terminal, but i'm starting to gather that it's not possible. I should just bite the bullet and figure out how to make SSH keys work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ftp protocol instead of scp try `ncftp` - it has nice batch interface